How to host appery ionic app on Windows IIS (HTML5)?
I created an application using Appery.io, appery offers publishing on their own hosting but, I need to publish the application on our internal windows IIS server.
Unfortunately, after searching through resources like StackOverflow and other forums, I couldn’t find a clear solution or guidance on how to achieve this.

You need download the app as a mobile web app, click EXPORT > HTML/JS/CSS:

Download the project and unzip it.
The folder should contain package.json.
From inside this catalog, start npm install (you need to have node.js and npm installed): all the dependencies will need to be installed from package.json.
Then run ionic serve which will start the project preview.
ionic build --prod will create the project build that can be then uploaded to whenever you need it.
